# How can I use assignment operations in the having clause?

Tags: sql, oracle

Here is my code.

```
SELECT BUSEO, SUBSTR(SSN,8,1)
FROM TBLINSA
GROUP BY BUSEO, SUBSTR(SSN,8,1)
HAVING (SUBSTR(SSN,8,1) = 2) >= 5;
```

What I intended was the condition that `substr(ssn,8,1)` must have a value of 2 and

`substr(ssn, 8, 1)=2` greater than 5.

But the result produced an SQL command not properly ended error.

I am wondering how I can fix this.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would be very helpful.   This doesn't make sense:  "substr(ssn, 8, 1)=2 greater than 5."

Answer (score 3):

I think you want the substring restriction in a `WHERE` clause.  Then aggregate by `BUSEO` and assert a count greater than or equal to 5.

```sql
SELECT BUSEO
FROM TBLINSA
WHERE SUBSTR(SSN, 8, 1) = '2'
GROUP BY BUSEO
HAVING COUNT(*) >= 5;
```